# Wordpress 4.0 CSRF Password Reset

Tags: passwords, csrf, metasploit, wordpress, metasploitable

I am working on a faculty project. I need to replicate Wordpress CSRF vulnerability on my localhost wordpress. I am trying to do this: https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/7691 
  I couldn't find any useful tutorials. I am thinking about using a Metasploit moduleon Kali Linux. Can someone guide me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Wordpress user can  go to this URL and request a password reset link via email:

```
https://yourwordpress.example/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
```

The reset link will look similar to this:

```
https://yourwordpress.example/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=dDnnToiqjYtsa9KdfVZl&login=admin
```

The `key` parameter in the URL ensures that only the reciever of the email is able to reset the password. After visiting the reset link you will be presented with a form to enter the new password.

Prior to Wordpress 4.0.1, this form didn't supply an anti-CSRF token. Instead, the `key` GET parameter is saved into a cookie and after submitting the new password the cookie value is verified.
This means that a user is vulnerable in the time between clicking on the password reset link and entering the new password. In that timeframe, *and only then*, an attacker could potentially launch a CSRF attack to change the password to an arbitrary value. (But because of this small window of opportunity the bug has limited value in a real-life attack.)

So to reproduce the vulnerability, you could do this:

- Request a password reset link. (e.g. for user `admin`)
- Visit the reset link (but don't enter a new password).
- Simulate a CSRF attack by submitting this form from an attacker-controlled domain with an arbitrary password:

  ```
  <form action="https://yourwordpress.example/wp-login.php?action=resetpass" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_login" value="admin">
      <input type="password" name="pass1">
      <input type="password" name="pass2">
      <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" value="Reset Password">
  </form>
  ```

The issue was [fixed](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/30418) by adding the reset token to the form (in addition to the cookie):

```
<input type="hidden" name="rp_key" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $rp_key ); ?>" />
```

And the reset attempt is invalidated when `rp_key` doesn't match:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) && ! hash_equals( $rp_key, $_POST['rp_key'] ) ) { 
    $user = false; 
}
```